# jquery ajax success function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this AJAX query in my project. I debug this script using Firebug but I am not able to find what is the error. Control is never going into the success function.

code :

```
    //send clicker data to div
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.clicker', function() {
            var data = $(this).attr('id');
            //alert(data);
            //var name = $(this).children('#hdName').attr('value');
            //  var Mobno = $(this).children('#hdMobile').attr('value');
            //var Comp = $(this).children('#hdCompany').attr('value');

            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $(".div-1").fadeOut(200).hide();

            $('.viewphn').val('');
            $('#txtMessage').val('');

            $('#txtMessage').val('');
            $('#user_MobileNo').val('');

            $('#User_Name').val('');
            $('#User_Email').val('');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: "db_data=" + data,

                success: function(data){                       
                    $('#hdpropidd').val(data);
                    $('#hdpropidd2').val(data);

                    //$('#ownername').val(name);
                    //$('#emailphnfield').val(Mobno);
                    //$('.span-11-xgj2').text(Comp);
                }
            })  
        });
    });
```

I am using this ajax in my project.I debug this script using firebug but not able to find what is error. Control is not going in success function.

Comment: where you specify the `url`, `contentType` kind of configurations

Comment: there is no url i am passing data in same page to another div

Comment: If you are passing data to another div on the same page, then I don't think there is a need for ajax. You can do it using jquery itself.

Comment: @applebud i want to pass data without refresh the page

Comment: Facepalm. @user3111053 I strongly recommend your to read some good book about html, css, and javascript book. Than you can start learning jquery library and ajax. However there is no point now to getting understand. And i did not understand who vote up for this question :(

Comment: I guess you want to achieve something like this.. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/appleBud/AsKnL/). It won't refresh your page every time.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you did not specified `url` parameter for your ajax call and it never succeeded. So your code not running to `success:` part. In order to fix this problem put `url:` to your ajax call and also use `error:` in order to get further error information.

Read more about ajax call [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). For example look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp).

> **By owner:** there is no url i am passing data in same page to another div

In this case i recommend you to use jQuery and read some books about javascript and jquery. Or at least if you know little bit about javascript watch [this](https://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/) tutorial in tutusplus.com for free.